# Install pants build tool on Anaconda 1.7.0

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, centos7, pants

I need to install pantsbuild on to an Anaconda python installation of 1.7.0. This is running on CentOS 7 and the Anaconda version cannot change.
I have set the PATH so that it points to the Anaconda installation of python.
So I cloned the github repo https://github.com/twitter/commons.git and tried to run ./pants. and I get the following output

```
Bootstrapping pants with requirements pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33
Using /opt/anaconda/bin/python2.7
~/codes/commons/build-support ~/codes/commons
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1572k  100 1572k    0     0  1364k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1372k
virtualenv-1.11.6/
virtualenv-1.11.6/AUTHORS.txt
virtualenv-1.11.6/bin/
virtualenv-1.11.6/bin/rebuild-script.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/conf.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/index.rst
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/make.bat
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/Makefile
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/news.rst
virtualenv-1.11.6/docs/virtualenv.rst
virtualenv-1.11.6/LICENSE.txt
virtualenv-1.11.6/MANIFEST.in
virtualenv-1.11.6/PKG-INFO
virtualenv-1.11.6/README.rst
virtualenv-1.11.6/scripts/
virtualenv-1.11.6/scripts/virtualenv
virtualenv-1.11.6/setup.cfg
virtualenv-1.11.6/setup.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/entry_points.txt
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/not-zip-safe
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/PKG-INFO
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.egg-info/top_level.txt
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/activate.bat
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/activate.csh
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/activate.fish
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/activate.ps1
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/activate.sh
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/activate_this.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/deactivate.bat
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/distutils-init.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/distutils.cfg
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_embedded/site.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_support/
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_support/__init__.py
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
virtualenv-1.11.6/virtualenv_support/setuptools-3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
~/codes/commons
New python executable in /root/codes/commons/build-support/python/../pants.venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /root/codes/commons/build-support/python/../pants.venv/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /root/codes/commons/build-support/python/../pants.venv/bin/python2.7 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/usr' (should be u'/root/codes/commons/build-support/pants.venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
build-support/python/libvirtualenv.sh: line 14: /root/codes/commons/build-support/python/../pants.venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pantsbuild.pants.contrib.scrooge==0.0.33 in /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pantsbuild.pants-0.0.33-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.collections>=0.3.1,<0.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.collections-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants.contrib.scrooge==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six==1.8.0 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.dirutil>=0.3.1,<0.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.dirutil-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.threading>=0.3.1,<0.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.threading-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.5.0,<2.6 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psutil==1.1.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil-1.1.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ansicolors==1.0.2 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansicolors-1.0.2-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pystache==0.5.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystache-0.5.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pex>=0.8.6,<0.8.999999 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pex-0.8.6-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.12,<0.13 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.12-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.confluence>=0.3.1,<0.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.confluence-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Markdown==2.1.1 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Markdown-2.1.1-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pygments==1.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.4-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.util>=0.3.1,<0.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.util-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.config>=0.3.1,<0.4 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.config-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lockfile==0.10.2 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lockfile-0.10.2-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zincutils==0.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zincutils-0.3-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): coverage>=3.7,<3.8 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coverage-3.7.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytest>=2.6,<2.7 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.6.4-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytest-cov>=1.8,<1.9 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_cov-1.8.1-py2.7.egg (from pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.lang==0.3.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.lang-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from twitter.common.collections>=0.3.1,<0.4->pantsbuild.pants.contrib.scrooge==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.log==0.3.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.log-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from twitter.common.confluence>=0.3.1,<0.4->pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.contextutil==0.3.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.contextutil-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from twitter.common.util>=0.3.1,<0.4->pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): py>=1.4.25 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py-1.4.30-py2.7.egg (from pytest>=2.6,<2.7->pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cov-core>=1.14.0 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cov_core-1.15.0-py2.7.egg (from pytest-cov>=1.8,<1.9->pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twitter.common.options==0.3.3 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter.common.options-0.3.3-py2.7.egg (from twitter.common.log==0.3.3->twitter.common.confluence>=0.3.1,<0.4->pantsbuild.pants==0.0.33)
Cleaning up...
./pants: line 29: exec: pants: not found
```

I am thinking its a version conflict between virtualenv and Anaconda. I would appreciate any advice to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend not running anything as root if at all possible.

The important bit of the error message is here:

```
ERROR: The executable /root/codes/commons/build-support/python/../pants.venv/bin/python2.7 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/usr' (should be u'/root/codes/commons/build-support/pants.venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I'm not sure what's different about Anaconda Python, but some Googling does reveal that Anaconda seems to be doing some of what virtualenv does, but differently.  So maybe there's a conflict?  If you just try installing and running vanilla virtualenv, that might make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Thanks David. The script I want to package depends heavily on Anaconda 1.7.0. I am not sure how to install virtualenv seperate from the Anaconda installation and use it to package my script.

Comment: I meant that virtualenv itself might be the problem.  But John Sirois mentioned on the pants mailing list that he is looking into this, so hopefully we'll get a resolution soon.